# Trying to get returned Ajax string to remain constant and not disappear when page is changed

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xml

as you can see in the code, I have a form which gets displayed by clicking on the "Edit" word. Then the user inputs his profile, which on submit, via Ajax, gets processed by a PHP script I have that saves it in SQL. Once saved, the form disappears and -theoretically- I would want the new profile to be copied back in there.

My question is: how do I get the to be fixed there, once I chance page? The SQL Update and .ajax work perfectly, but when I change page and go back here, I lose what's inside the div and the user won't be able to see his newly saved profile link.

As you can see, I have a session variable with the profile in the code which I print so that when user gain's first access to his account, he sees his profile. Unfortunately, this remains after he's saved the new profile.

I'd be really glad if you could help, it's been days now I've tried to get my head around this. Thank you very much!

```
<?php
    session_start();  
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
?>

<html>
<style>
    #form1{display:none;}
</style>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("document").ready(function(){
            $(".js-ajax-php-json").submit(function(){
                var data = {"action": "test"};
                data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "tryoutwo.php", 
                    data: data,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $(".the-return").html(data["profile"]);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body> 
    <div class="container">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><p><b>My Facebook profile:</b></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="the-return"></div>
                    <p id="editprofile"><? php print($profile); ?>
                        <form action="return.php" onsubmit="hideform()" class="js-ajax-php-json" method="post" id="form1">
                            <input type="text" name="profile" value=""/> 
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit form">
                        </form>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td><p onclick="return showform()"><a href>Edit</a></p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script>
        function showform() {
            document.getElementById("form1").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("editprofile").innerHTML = "";
            return false;
        }

        function hideform() {
            document.getElementById("form1").style.display = 'none';
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why can't you update the session variable? Alternatively store it in browser localStorage

Comment: Hi Charlietfl, sorry I'm not that experienced. That definitely helped, thank you so much!!

G.R.

Comment: charlietfl, please repeat your comment as an answer, so that Nockingham can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do:

```
<?php
session_start();
if( isset( $_POST['profile'] ) )
    $_SESSION['profile'] = $_POST['profile'];
?>
```

and the html

```
<p id="editprofile">
<?php 
if( isset( $_SESSION['profile'] ) ) 
    echo $_SESSION['profile']; ?>
</p>
```